# QGraphicsRectItem local coordinate not working in Qt 4.8

Tags: c++, qt, coordinates, qgraphicsitem

I'm trying to write a simple program in C++ using Qt 4.8 and I got stuck with this issue:
I want a QGraphicsRectItem to be the parent of another one. When the parent is showed, anyway, the child is shown outside, as if it was using scene coordinates instead of parent's local coordinates.
Here is my code

```
    QGraphicsRectItem* qRect = new QGraphicsRectItem(x,y,width,height);
QGraphicsRectItem* qRect2 = new QGraphicsRectItem(0,0,100, 100, qRect);
    qRect2->setParentItem(qRect);

_pcChooseMenuScene->addItem(qRect);
_game.getGameGraphicsView()->setScene(_pcChooseMenuScene);
```

[The output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1lDg.png)

Have I misunderstood the parent/child relationship, does it not work in this case or is this a version issue?
Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: I suggest subclassing the class and overriding the [paint function](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsrectitem.html#paint) to also draw the coordinates of each item. You'll learn a lot about coordinate systems that way. Also, check out the [pos()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#pos) that is set for both items. Finally, what are the values for x,y,width,height?

Comment: y,widht,height are values depending on the viewport size. In this particular case y = viewport_height/2, width = viewport_width - 2*a_margin_value and height = viewport_height/2-a_margin. x = a_margin_value, again, thus I have the parent rect item in the position that's shown in the figure. I don't understand why the child isn't positioned in the center of the parent, as the documentation states.

Comment: I've followed your suggestion and printed the values for qRect (the parent) pos and qRect2 (the child) pos. The parent pos is (0,0)... don't really know why, since I have "told" the constructor to put the rect in (x,y). If I eventually call qRect->setPos(x,y) it works. Still, I wonder why.

Comment: **I have "told" the constructor to put the rect in (x,y)** - the constructor is setting the local coordinates of the item, not the coordinates of the scene. When you add the item (parent) to the scene, it will start at (0,0) in scene coordinates, but it's local coordinates won't have changed.

Comment: Ok. I think i got it:
(x,y) define the position of the rendered QRectF inside the item. The item will be placed in the scene center (0,0) (upper left corner in this case) and thus its local coordinate system starts there as well.
If I call the constructor passing 0,0 and then eventually call setPos(x,y) I get the whole item put in (x,y) which will be the center of the new local coords system.

Comment: Yup, that sounds about right. I personally prefer defining all items inherited from `QGraphicsItem` (or `QGraphicsObject` if you want signal and slots) and setting their bounding rect so that their local centre point is at (0,0) by using (-width/2, -height/2, width, height). setPos(0,0) will now place the origin at the centre of the parent item, in relation to its parent, rather than at the top left.